# react toogle state value on keydown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a function that will toggle the state when I click a certain button.

```
const keydown = () => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "KeyY") {
        setSortOpen(!sortOpen);
      }
    });
  };
```

Here, what I expect is whenever I click the `Y` button, it will toggle the state value, but what I got it will only change at the initial click, and the rest of the test would give the same output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [sortOpen, setSortOpen] = useState(false);

  window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.code === "KeyY") {
      setSortOpen(!sortOpen);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {sortOpen ? "true" : "false"}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure how your implementation looks like but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `useState` hook if you want to toggle the state when the button clicked.

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) is more information about `useState`

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [sortOpen,setSortOpen] = useState(false);

const keydown = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
    setSortOpen(!sortOpen);
    console.log(sortOpen);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
  <button onClick={keydown}>Click</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```